# error in MySql syntax near = in where clause

Tags: php

i am writing this command

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register where name= ‘lakhan’ ") or die(mysql_error());
```

and when running the php file it shows:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘lakhan’'
```

I am using MySql Server 5.5 AND INSTEAD OF = sign i have used LIKE also in query then too error is coming.Please help me to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes arround the value:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register where name= 'lakhan' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Do not longer use the deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`with prepared statements.

Comment: I have use single quotes only then too error is coming

Comment: @RamSomani Which errors?

Comment: The error is resolved thanks....the single quots will be used around the query instead of double quots